# Setting Formula for Range in Excel not possible in C# if Range is greater than 1

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to automate some formula insertion in Excel with C#.
The problem is, that the function works as long as the Range is of the size 1.
So setting the formula for:

with formula being: "=IF(B2="",0,1)"

startingCell: "A2"

endingCell: "A2"

```cs
        public static string SetFormula(string formula, string startingCell, string endingCell)
        {
            try
            {
                Range range = worksheet.Range[startingCell, endingCell].Cells;
                foreach(Range cell in range.Rows)
                {
                    cell.Formula = formula;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }
```

this works flawlessly.

I have tried earlier setting the whole range at once

```cs
        public static string SetFormula(string formula, string startingCell, string endingCell)
        {
            try
            {
                worksheet.Range[startingCell, endingCell].Formula= formula;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }
```

but it all ends with the following error when executing, as soon as the range extends more than 1 cell.

```cs
private static Application application;
        private static Workbook workbook;
        private static Worksheet worksheet;

        private const string SUCCESS = "success";
        public static void InitExcelConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                application = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
                application.Visible = true;
                application.DisplayAlerts = false;
            }
            catch (COMException e)
            {
                application = new Application();
                application.Visible = true;
                application.DisplayAlerts = false;
            }
        }

        public static string OpenWorkbookAndSheet(string filepath, string sheetname)
        {
            try
            {
                workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
                worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetname];
                worksheet.Activate();
                return SUCCESS;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }


        public static string SetFormula(string formula, string startingCell, string endingCell)
        {
            try
            {
                Range range = worksheet.Range[startingCell, endingCell].Cells;
                foreach(Range cell in range.Rows)
                {
                    cell.Formula = formula;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }

        public static long GetRowNumber()
        {
            return worksheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                               System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                               XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                               false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;
        }


        public static string SaveWorkbook()
        {
            try
            {
                workbook.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }

        public static string CloseExcel()
        {
            try
            {
                application.DisplayAlerts = true;
                application.Workbooks.Close();
                application.Quit();

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
                return SUCCESS;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
Exception to HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

Comment: `Range cell in range.Rows` enumerates rows, one at a time, and each row may be several cells. Because it works there (setting the formula to the entire row at a time), there must be something else that breaks your second piece of code.

Comment: I couldn't guess what. The Excel application opens correctly and it crashes when trying to enter the formula. I have other code without formulas which works fine

Comment: Please come up with the minimum amount of code that [reproduces](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem and does not depend on any other code that is not shown.

Comment: @GSerg sure I'm sorry about that, I'm leaving on purpose 1 function in which operates on ranges as well but works fine